# background service android

Tags: android

In oncreate() method i call

new loadingTask().execute()

which execute the background service beneath:

class loadingTask extends AsyncTask {

Comment: Where do you set `envelope`? That's `null`.

Comment: ok i solved it after posting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception says there is a NullPointerException in your doInBackground method

```
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null format argument
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2173)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2151)
04-04 10:39:25.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2532):     at .Convertor$loadingTask.doInBackground(Convertor.java:201)
```

as it is related to the String.format() call according to the exception, i think in this line

```
 String requestEnvelope=String.format(envelope, "28-03-2013","true");
```

your `envelope` variable is NULL.